# C++ Make file issue "No rule to make target ..."

Tags: c++, makefile

I just started working with makefile. 
I am getting the error with makefile of my C++ project.

**make:  No rule to make target 'bin/smartCart_app', needed by all.**
 Below is the directory structure and files associated with it.

```
VBOX:~BASE$ls
build src 
VBOX:~BASE$cd build
VBOX:~BASE/build$ ls
bin build Makefile.sc 
VBOX:~BASE/build$ cd ../src
VBOX:~BASE/src$ls
baseStation.cpp config util //config and util has header and cpp files
```

Here is my Make file

```
CC=gcc
CPP=g++
CCFLAGS=-g -Wall -std=gnu+0x -o0 
CC_LDFLAGS = -g -Wl 

BUILD=./build
BIN = ./bin

SC_SRC_ROOT = ../src
SC_SRC_SUBDIRS = config util 
SC_SRC_RELDIRS = $(addprefix $(strip $(SC_SRC_ROOT)), $(strip $(SC_SRC_SUBDIRS)))
SC_SRCS_ = $(shell /usr/bin/find $(SC_SRC_ROOT)/config $(SC_SRC_ROOT)/util -name "*.cpp")
SC_SRCS = $(SC_SRCS_) baseStation.cpp
SC_NEW_SRCS = $(notdir $(SC_SRCS))

SPACE :=
SPACE += 
INCLUDE = $(addprefix -I, $(SRC_RELDIRS))
VPATH = $(subst $(SPACE),:,$(SRC_RELDIRS)) $(subst $(SPACE),:,$(SC_SRC_RELDIRS))
SC_INCLUDE = $(addprefix -I, $(SC_SRC_RELDIRS))

SC_OBJS = $(SC_NEW_SRCS:%.cpp=$(BUILD)/%.o)
SC_DEPS = $(SC_OBJS:%.o=%.d)

# Ensure paths exist.
$(shell [ -d "$(BIN)"   ] || mkdir -p $(BIN))
$(shell [ -d "$(BUILD)" ] || mkdir -p $(BUILD))

# Explicit rules.
.PHONY: all clean $(PHONY)
all: $(BIN)/smartCart_app

clean: 
        @echo "Cleaning..."
        -@rm -f $(BIN)/smartCart_app $(SC_OBJS) 

$(SC_OBJS): $(BUILD)/%.o: %.cpp
     @echo "Compiling $(notdir $<)"
    @$(CPP) $(CCFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) $(SC_INCLUDE) -MD -c -o $@ $<

$(MACRO_DEPS):
    -@rm -f $(patsubst %_ON.d,%_OFF.d,$@) $(patsubst %_OFF.d,%_ON.d,$@) $@
    @touch $@

#$(ALL_OBJS): %.o: %.d

$(DEPS): $(BUILD)/%.d: %.cpp
    @$(CC) $< -MM -MF $@ $(INCLUDE)
```

Comment: Had you considered that maybe there is *"no rule to make target 'bin/smartCart_app'"* (which is required by the target *all*)?

Comment: I added the rule now as below. Now, it gives no rule to make target baseStation.cpp" needed by build/baseStation.o
# Explicit rules.
.PHONY: all clean $(PHONY)
all: $(BIN)/smartCart_app

$(BIN)/smartCart_app: $(SC_OBJS)
   @echo "Linking $(notdir $@)"
  @$(CPP) -o $@ $^ $(CC_LDFLAGS)
clean: 
  ..    Looks like I am missing something very important. Please explain.

Comment: Have you considered that maybe there is "no rule to make target ''baseStation.cpp" (which is required by the target build/baseStation.o)? :-) If baseStation.cpp is not in the current directory, you need to add the path to VPATH (I guess it isn't in src/config or src/util otherwise you'd get another error)

Comment: also, `SC_SRC_RELDIRS` is incorrect (missing `/` after `$(SC_SRC_ROOT)`)

Comment: I am able to compile the code. I was able to fix the above issue "/" which was also found by @ComeRaczy.